# Can't use an App that uses Workflow 2013 on SharePoint Server version

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2015, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow, hosted-app

I am trying to install an SharePoint 2013 SharePoint-hosted app with Workflows through App Catalog, but always receiving "Sorry, this app is not supported on your server".

Thank you in advance!

[msdn link without solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e8d0a27b-071e-4f11-b768-905a239aee9f/cant-an-an-app-that-uses-workflow-2013-on-sharepoint-server-version?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e8d0a27b-071e-4f11-b768-905a239aee9f/cant-an-an-app-that-uses-workflow-2013-on-sharepoint-server-version?forum=appsforsharepoint)